# Apache rewrite requests to build/public folder with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I often have projects that produce some sort of output folder, usually named build or public or something like that. But if I deploy my entire project to an Apache web server, in order to route to the actual project you would have to do it like this: `https://example.com/user/project/build/file`.

To simplify and shorten the url, how can I rewrite requests in a .htaccess file so that if google for `user/project/file` it automatically routes it to `user/project/build/file`?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just set the `DocumentRoot` to `/var/www/example.com/user/project/build` rather than `/var/www/example.com` in the Apache configuration file for the virtual host?  (Usually `/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf`.)

Comment: Because it's not my server. It's a shared server and I don't have access to anything other than my user directory.

Comment: Then why upload the entire source tree, why not just deploy what is built to the webserver?

Answer (score 2):

The best usually is to place only those files under the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` that are actually meant to be directly published by the http server. That also typically simplifies the URL to access them. The rest of the files, scripts and ressources should be kept *outside* the `DOCUMENT_ROOT`. You can still access them inside your application logic.

Sometimes this is not possible though. For example if you are using a cheap hosting service instead of operating your own http server. In such case request rewriting comes in as an alternative. In this situation you also typically have to rely on distributed configuration files (".htaccess") instead of being able to use the usual http server's host configuration. That comes with a few disadvantages, but sometimes it is your only option.

Have a try using such an implementation:

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteRule ^/?user/project/build/(.*)$ /user/project/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/?user/project/(.*)$ /user/project/build/$1 [END]
```

This relies on the rewriting module being loaded and activated in the http server, obviously. And also the usage of distribute configuration files needs to be enabled for the http host and the requested location.

Always test using a fresh anonymous browser instance (to prevent caching issues in your tests). It also makes sense to start out using a `R=302` *temporary* redirection first and only to change that to a `R=301` *permanent* redirection once everything works as expected.

Comment: @MrWhite Thanks for the hints. The issue is my keyboard which swallows characters when not pressed hard enough :-(